# How do I create a separate swift file and call the function in it later?

Tags: swift, function

I have an Xcode project in Swift I'm creating.  In my main View Controller, it is taking a long time to load because of all the functions in it.  I think that if I create a swift file and call this later, it will speed up my project and not have as long of code in my main View Controller.  I'm trying to create a separate Swift file that will have some functions in it, and then call this into the main View Controller.  I created a Swift file and called it 'sunday.swift'.  A piece of the code that will got into it is:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIView {
    func codedSundayButtons(){
    //Chore 1 (RED)
    ButtonSunChore1R.viewWithTag(0)
    ButtonSunChore1R.setBackgroundImage(sunC1R, forState: .Normal)
    ButtonSunChore1R.addTarget(self, action: "ButtonSunChore1Ra:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    addSubview(ButtonSunChore1R)

    //Chore 1 (YELLOW)
    ButtonSunChore1Y.viewWithTag(1)
    ButtonSunChore1Y.setBackgroundImage(sunC1Y, forState: .Normal)
    ButtonSunChore1Y.addTarget(self, action: "ButtonSunChore1Ya:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    addSubview(ButtonSunChore1Y)
    }
}
```

Within the newly created Swift file, I will create the button actions, etc. and a lot more buttons. How do I call this sunday.swift file and codedSundayButtons function in my main View Controller.

I've tried writing this question in the correct format so I don't get flagged for doing it wrong and not be able to post anymore questions.

Comment: The number of methods in your viewcontroller shouldn't be affecting performance much at all. You may have other underlying causes of the slowdown. Code from your viewcontroller would help shine a light on it

Comment: There's too much to paste into it.  Thank you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, this is not the problem for the slow loading.

Anyways here is how you would accomplish what you are wanting to do:

Create a file called `LanguageExtensions.swift`

```
extension UIView {
    func codedSundayButtons(#firstButton: UIButton, secondButton: UIButton){
        //Chore 1 (RED)
        ButtonSunChore1R.viewWithTag(0)
        ButtonSunChore1R.setBackgroundImage(sunC1R, forState: .Normal)
        ButtonSunChore1R.addTarget(self, action: "ButtonSunChore1Ra:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.addSubview(ButtonSunChore1R)

        //Chore 1 (YELLOW)
        ButtonSunChore1Y.viewWithTag(1)
        ButtonSunChore1Y.setBackgroundImage(sunC1Y, forState: .Normal)
        ButtonSunChore1Y.addTarget(self, action: "ButtonSunChore1Ya:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.addSubview(ButtonSunChore1Y)
    }
}
```

And call it using: `yourView.codedSundayButtons(firstButton: ButtonSunChore1R, secondButton: ButtonSunChore1Y)`

Comment: Is there a reason to use 'LanguageExtensions' instead of 'sunday'? Thank you.

Comment: @ChallengerGuy It's just a better naming convention. "sunday" isn't really a good name for a file containing extensions.

Comment: Please explain why you think this makes sense as an extension on `UIView`, and why you recommend naming the .swift file *LanguageExtensions*.

Comment: @jlehr I don't think this makes any sense as an extension. I only told him how to achieve what he wanted to do with the code that he already had. `LanguageExtensions.swift` would be a good name (at least in my opinion) for a .swift file that contains all extensions in a project.

Comment: What meaning does the word 'language' have in that context?

Comment: Advising people to persist in doing things that don't make sense isn't the best way to help them.

Comment: @jlehr I did not have a better answer and since no one else provided any help, I did what I could. 'Language' as in Swift as a programming language. I wanted to at least provide a better name than 'sunday.' Since you obviously know more than me, can you submit an answer to help @ChallengerGuy? I will gladly remove mine as I never intended for it to be the best answer to this post. I only had it as a last resort of no on else provided a solution.